# SnakeYAML: How to disable underscore stripping when parsing?

Tags: parsing, yaml, snakeyaml

Here's my problem. I have YAML doc that contains the following pair:

`run_ID: 2010_03_31_101`

When this get's parsed  at
`org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.ConstructYamlInt:159`
underscores get stripped and Constructor returns `Long 20100331101`
instead of unmodified `String "2010_03_31_101"` that I really need.

QUESTION: How
can I disable this behavior and force parser to use String constructor
instead of Long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. Got answer form their mailing list. Here it is

> Hi, according to the spec
>   (http://yaml.org/type/int.html): Any
>   “_” characters in the number are
>   ignored, allowing a readable
>   representation of large values
>
> You have a few ways to solve it. 1) do
>   not rely on implicit types, use quotes
>   (single or double) run_ID:
>   '2010_03_31_101'
>
> 2) Turn off resolver for integers (as
>   it is done here for floats) [link
>   1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/examples/resolver/CustomResolverTest.java&usg=AFQjCNFvDg8-gQOLyN6hYkB6-ni9SPZ7OA) [link 2](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/examples/resolver/CustomResolver.java&usg=AFQjCNGFpS9VB-uLcrQuB2fdOy16rUVPTQ)
>
> 3) Define your own pattern for int
>   [link 3](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/examples/resolver/CustomIntResolver.java&usg=AFQjCNEnqpdzy93jm4v0995UvoZbSE5Yog)
>
> Please be aware that when you start to
>   deviate from the spec other recipients
>   may fail to parse your YAML document.
>   Using quotes is safe.
>
> - Andrey

Comment: Links are dead.